# Trying to get user id and user meta data from WordPress database

Tags: sql, wordpress, inner-join

I am trying to get a list of all users in WordPress getting the user ID from the user table and some additional meta information from the usermeta table for the corresponding user. I am trying the below code but it's not working. I think I am going wrong in the INNER JOIN part of the statement but I don't know how to correct it.

```
$sql = "
SELECT {$wpdb->users}.ID,{$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value
FROM {$wpdb->users},{$wpdb->usermeta} 
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} ON ({$wpdb->users}.ID = {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id)
WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'first_name' OR {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'last_name' OR {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'dev_capabilities'         
";

$users = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

*p.s. I realise there's easier ways to get this information in WordPress by using the [get_users()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) function but because this is in a particular action I can't use this method.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You are actually, accidentally, joining in your usermeta data in twice. Once as as an implicit cross join with the `,` and once again as an explicit INNER JOIN. Instead:

```
$sql = "
SELECT {$wpdb->users}.ID,{$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value
FROM {$wpdb->users} INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} ON ({$wpdb->users}.ID = {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id)
WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'first_name' OR {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'last_name' OR {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'dev_capabilities'         
";

$users = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

---

To get first and last name as well as dev capabilities in the same record (and, I assume, in the same array that $wpdb outputs) you can inner join to that meta table three times. Sticking each one of those into a subquery makes it easy to parse what's happening:

```
$sql = "
SELECT {$wpdb->users}.ID, firstname.meta_value as first_name, lastname.meta_value as last_name, devcapabilities.meta_value as dev_capabilities
FROM {$wpdb->users} 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, meta_value FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE meta_key = 'first_name') as firstname ON {$wpdb->users}.ID = firstname.user_id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, meta_value FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE meta_key = 'last_name') as lastname ON {$wpdb->users}.ID = lastname.user_id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, meta_value FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE meta_key = 'dev_capabilities') as devcapabilities ON {$wpdb->users}.ID = devcapabilities.user_id
";

$users = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks JNevill. When I print this out each meta value is in a separate array, so it's like: 

  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'ID' => '2',
     'meta_value' => 'Martin',
  )),

stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'ID' => '2',
     'meta_value' => 'Gibson',
  )),

is it possible to put this into a single array? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that part since that array output is specific to the `$wpdb->get_results` function. Which is a wordpress specific function for retrieving and transforming the SQL result set that you send to it. Since the issue of how to get the data out of the database is resolved in this question, it would be prudent to ask a new question with the `wordpress` tag asking if it's possible to get a single array back from `$wpdb`.

Comment: Thanks JNevill, I should be able to reconstruct this so it's in the right format. I just wasn't sure if perhaps the way the query was structured was causing the output to be a certain way. Thanks,

Comment: Ah! ok. That makes sense. The query itself is just going to output a simple record for each `user.id / meta_value` that it finds. For example: `2 | 'Martin'` and `2 | 'Gibson'`. If you want first and lastname in the same record, then you will (oddly enough) need to join the meta table in twice, both with an inner join. I think a subquery would be the right way to go. I will post that with the answer in case it helps.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for your help, it's really appreciated

Comment: That updated answer worked once I removed the where clause. This could be a WordPress thing rather than an SQL thing. Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: I forgot to remove that pesky where clause. Sorry about that. I've updated the answer to reflect the change.

Comment: No worries, appreciate your time and answer